# Can't load js file into child theme for Wordpress

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a custom js file into a child theme. I have set up a folder within the child themes directory on FTP that contains a js file, but it does not work. Below is my code i used to enque the file.

```
 <?php
function theme_name_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', /js/public.js);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
?>
```

Comment: Looks like a syntax error by the syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', /js/public.js);
```

With

```
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', '/js/public.js');
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply. Unfortunately, the child's js doesn't seem to replace the parents js.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load js file into child theme for Wordpress your code should like this.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

function theme_name_scripts() {

 wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);

}
?>
```

Comment: thankyou for the reply. tested this and it doesn't override the parents js